# How can I disabled sub menu item in react?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I create a menu with React.js. But there is a problem for me. There is 2 sub menus and these sub menus have their menu items. When I hover one of them it shows its menu items. But when I click another sub menu, it still shows previous menu items. How can I prevent it ? My code:

My first class : Sider.js

```
function Sider(props) {
  return (
     <Menu mode="horizontal">
     selectedKeys={[props.current]}
     onClick={props.handleClick}
       <SubMenu title={<span><Icon type="setting" />Sub menu 1</span>}>
         <MenuItem> menu item 1</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem> menu item 2</MenuItem>
       </SubMenu>
       <SubMenu title={<span><Icon type="laptop" />Sub menu 2</span>}>
         <MenuItem> menu item 3</MenuItem>
       </SubMenu>
     </Menu>
  );
}
```

This is my main class which I call Sider function.

Main.js :

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Main extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
         current: 'MenuItem'
      }
   }

   handleClick = (e) => {
      this.setState({
         current: e.key,
      });
   }

   render() {
     return (
        <div>
          <Sider navigation={this.props.navigation} handleClick={this.props.handleClick} current={this.state.current />
        </div>
     );
   }
}

Main.propTypes = {
   handleClick: PropTypes.func,
};
```

Comment: Sub menu should be active when you click on that. Correct?

Comment: yes correct and then this sub menu closed to open another sub menu @elumalai_kp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `key` to maintain active `state` of selected sub menu and use `selectedKeys`. see the working code below

I have made working menu in codeopen here [codepen](https://codepen.io/elumalaiit/pen/NwXLxa)

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    current: 'menu1:1',
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Sider navigation={this.props.navigation} handleClick={this.handeClick} current={this.state.current} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
   handleClick: PropTypes.func,
};
```

And your `Sider` function will be like below

```
function Sider(props) {
  return (
     <Menu onClick={props.handleClick} selectedKeys={[props.current]}>
       <SubMenu title={<span><Icon type="setting" />Sub menu 1</span>}>
         <MenuItem key="setting:1"> menu item 1</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem key="setting:2"> menu item 2</MenuItem>
       </SubMenu>
       <SubMenu title={<span><Icon type="laptop" />Sub menu 2</span>}>
         <MenuItem key="laptop:1"> menu item 3</MenuItem>
       </SubMenu>
     </Menu>
  );
}
```

For documentations please read [horizontal menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-horizontal) and [Vertical Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-vertical)

Comment: I don't understand where I should place the handleClick in my code ? I have  App class and Sider class. In your code both of them in one class

Comment: You probably should place onclick on menu. I assumed  menu itself as  an App. Or pass onclick and state as props to your `sider` function in your scenario. Hope you will get an idea!

Comment: @willywonka15 - See the updated answer you will get an idea how to do!

Comment: Thank you so much. I see your updated answer its help me but there is still a problem and I can't how can I figure out it ? Could you see my updated answer, please ?

Comment: The problem is in Sider.js there is a warning: handleClick is missing prop validation.

Comment: Are you getting `current` prop in `Sider.js`?

Comment: I used it but the same warning opens.

Comment: Please go through this codepen done with `Sidebar` function like you did and couldn't see any warnings https://codepen.io/elumalaiit/pen/NwXLxa.

Comment: The reason of warning should be I add props in the Main.js not App.js ?

Comment: @willywonka15 - You can't access as `React.PropTypes.func` as of React 16. So import `prop-types` package and use as `PropTypes.func` and will work!

Answer (score 0):

How did you implement the hovering mechanism? Please add more code.
Do you change the inner state of each SubMenu when you hover out?

You should better read the documentation for antd's components.
Go to the following [link](https://ant.design/components/menu/#components-menu-demo-sider-current) to better understand how to use these components.

Comment: No, I didn't how can I do that?

Comment: I need to see more of the code, did you create the Menu, SubMenu components or are you importing them from a third party?

Comment: I add my render function.

Comment: I edited the answer, please try using the attached link.

Comment: I read but my menu is different a little from that link. Shoul I add mountMode ? Which one close sub menu items ?

Comment: Looks like you should use inner state to determine which submenu is currently open. When you open another submenu, you should change the current submenu and that way only the current submenu will be open.

Comment: Ok, I understand but I didn't do that :/ I add a handleClick function to set state but it doesnt't work